# Is it posible to pass a C function as callback to OCaml?

Tags: c++, c, ocaml

I'm studying on how to integrate an OCaml TCP/IP stack into my C++ project. I already know how to call C from OCaml and call OCaml from C thanks to this answer: [OCaml as C library, hello world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416259/ocaml-as-c-library-hello-world-example)

The OCaml will be controlled by C++, not the other way around. So, for a TCP/IP stack, I must be able to send and receive packets. I can easily send data to the TCP/IP stack through C++, but how to receive it? I need to pass a C function (a callback) as a parameter to OCaml so it delivers the data when it arrives. Is it possible?

Comment: The best solution would be the one that gets the job done the most elegantly, so with fewest stack possible, I would go for full C++ if I were in your shoes. What makes OCaml TCP/IP stack so interesting that you want an integration ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL there's no simple TCP/IP stack in C++ and C ones are mostly ports of giant codes from FreeBSD or Linux. This one is one of the few I considered but as you can see it makes ultra heavy usage of templates making it unmaintanable or unreadable https://github.com/ambrop72/aipstack/blob/master/examples/aipstack_example.cpp#L107

Comment: There's a separate section dealing with exactly this in the manual: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s:c-callback. I see this is references in the answer you point to, but as the title is literally "callbacks from C to OCaml" I'm wondering what specifically this doesn't answer for you.

Comment: @glennsl as I understood, this is a way to call OCaml from C and get a result back. What I want is to pass a C function as a parameter to OCaml who will then be free to call this C function as a callback in the future. It's not the same thing.

Comment: Right. I'm no FFI expert, but I don't think it's possible to pass a function pointer around as an OCaml closure. You might have to use a named C function that can execute a given function pointer, and call that manually from OCaml with the function pointer passed to it.from C.

Comment: @glennsl you mean pass the `int64_t` number from the function pointer to the OCaml side and then call the C `execute_function_pointer(int64_t function_pointer)`? What you mean by an OCaml closure?

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. A [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) is essentially a function pointer that also carries an "environment" containing all the variables that were in scope when defining the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two C functions for that. The first one (`wrap_fun` below) is called from C code. It takes a C callback and returns an OCaml value that you can then pass to your OCaml code. The second one (`call_wrapped` below) is called from the OCaml code. It takes an OCaml value created by the first function and calls the callback stored into it.

You did not specify anything about the signature of your callback, so the code below goes for `value(value)`.

```c
#include <caml/alloc.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>

typedef value (*cb)(value);

value wrap_fun(cb f) {
  value v = caml_alloc_small(1, Abstract_tag);
  Field(v, 0) = (value)f;
  return v;
}

value call_wrapped(value f, value x) {
  CAMLparam2(f, x);
  cb g = (cb)Field(f, 0);
  value z = g(x);
  CAMLreturn(z);
}
```

On the OCaml side, it looks as follows:

```ml
external call_wrapped : ('a, 'b) wrapped_fun -> 'a -> 'b  = "call_wrapped"

let foo f x =
  let y = x + 1 in
  let z = call_wrapped f y in
  z ^ "a"
```

The `CAMLparam2` and `CAMLreturn` macros in `call_wrapped` are just there for didactic purpose. They can safely be removed, since the function is just a wrapper to the actual function.

Comment: On the OCaml side, you also need `type ('a, 'b) wrapped_fun` to declare the new type constructor.